# How can I pass a rust function as a callback in a windows dll?

Tags: rust, dll, ffi

I need to use a windows dll in Rust which requires a callback function. I've already used it in VB6 and C# but couldn't seem to do it in Rust.

VB6 Code:

```
Public Declare Sub Init Lib "DeviceDrv.dll" Alias "INIT" (ByRef iCallbackAddress As Long)
```

Usage:

```
Public Sub InitialiseCallback(ByVal iStation As Integer, ByVal iValue As Single)
    ...
End Sub

Call Init(AddressOf InitialiseCallback)
```

C# Code:

```
[DllImport("DeviceDrv.dll", EntryPoint = "INIT", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = false)]
public static extern void Init(IntPtr callback);
```

Usage:

```
public delegate void InitialiseCallback(int station, float value);

public static void InitCallback(int station, float value)
{
    ...
...
}
...
...
var cb = new InitialiseCallback(InitCallback);
GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(cb);
_callbackPointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(cb);
Init(_callbackPointer);
```

Please tell me what is the equivalent code in Rust.

I have already tried doing the following in Rust:

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
#[link(name = "DeviceDrv", kind = "static")]
extern {
    pub fn INIT(callback: unsafe extern "C" fn(i32, f32));
}

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn cb(station: i32, value: f32) {
    ...
}

crate::dd::INIT(cb);
```

This code compiles without error but does not work as expected.

Comment: What does "does not work as expected" mean? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

Comment: The callback is not getting called.

Comment: Both `extern` blocks should probably be `extern "system" { ... }`. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry, that didn't fix the problem. Thanks for trying!